# How to setup a server for Mac App distribution?

Tags: distribution

I would like to independently setup a server or find a third party who can host my applications for the Mac. I would like to use this method to distribute my applications. For someone with zero background in this distribution method, what is the easiest path (my apps are already on the app store) to take?

Any and all of your recommendations would greatly be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to shortcut the App store entirely here? Doesn't the App store already distribute them for you?

Comment: Yes. Because of Apple's restrictions, I had to "dumb down" my apps. I would like to release my apps the way it is meant to be used (with all features). That's why I am trying to find another method to distribute my apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that you actually submit it to Apple and they host your application etc. There is no need to have server infrastructure in place for distribution. You will only need server infrastructure if there is some component of the application that talks to a service you are providing.

Comment: I am looking for an alternative method to Apple's app store (which I am now using). To do so I somehow need to build or find a third party who can host my applications (sort of like Cydia for iPhone apps).

Comment: There are no "third-party app stores" that I'm aware of -- You can set up your own site on any web host and use Paypal or similar to take payments, or try standard retail channels...